# Páginas archivo json con ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hola amigos tengo un archivo json algo pesado construido clave valor aquí un fragmento.

```json
{
  "3d_rotation": "e84d",
  "ac_unit": "eb3b",
  "access_alarm": "e190",
  "access_alarms": "e191",
  "access_time": "e192",
  "accessibility": "e84e",
  "accessible": "e914",
  "account_balance": "e84f",
  "account_balance_wallet": "e850",
  "account_box": "e851",
  "account_circle": "e853",
  "adb": "e60e",
  "add": "e145",
  "add_a_photo": "e439",
  "add_alarm": "e193",
  "add_alert": "e003",
  "add_box": "e146",
  "add_circle": "e147",
  "add_circle_outline": "e148",
  "add_location": "e567",
  "add_shopping_cart": "e854",
  "add_to_photos": "e39d",
  "add_to_queue": "e05c",
  "adjust": "e39e",
}
```

Ese archivo tiene aproximadamente 25.500 líneas de código.
Mi pregunta es como puedo paginarlo para crear un modal con Metro y laravel para que los usuarios puedan seleccionar el icono a incluir.
intente usar `$.ajax` pero se tarda demasiado solo en abrir el diálogo. Ese problema lo tengo con los icono y animaciones. de mi sistema estoy creando un mini blog en laravel y uno de los requerimientos es qu puedan crear listas con Iconos los cuales me los pasaron.

Comment: No has pensado que un usuario normal ¿Agotaría su plan de datos si llegara a **ver** tu blog? ... O, tal vez, ¡no entendí lo que quieres hacer!

Comment: En realidad si tienes poco megas puedes usar el buscador aunque debes saberte el nombre del icon, pero si no sabes lo que quieres te doy el dialogo que actualmente te congela el equipo por 8seg, antes de solo abrir el modal.

Comment: Problema que deseo resolver y creo que si puedo mostrarte fragmentos de ese archivo que cabe destacar esta en otro servido por razones de espacio, seria excelente porque solo te mostraria 50 icon por pagina que es lo quiero hacer pero no puedo

Comment: Ajax te permite hacer carga escalonada. 1. Carga la página limpia (para que sea rápido) 2. En evento onload invoca cargar grupo pequeño (10 iconos) en .done los muestras. 3. si no viene marca de final haces llamado recursivo para halar siguiente bloque. Así la página carga rápido y en lugar de congelarse el usuario ve aparecer progresivamente el grupo de iconos.

Comment: bueno acabas de describirme lo que quiero hacer pero no se como hacerlos ya que al cargar domain.com/icons.json me trae todos los iconos ayi es donde tengo el rollo yo no quiero todos los icono solo 50 por carga, con php y mysql solo consultaria 50 resultados

Comment: pero como le digo a un archivo .json que solo me traiga los primeros 50 resultados?????

Comment: Haz un script en el servidor que se encargue de leer todo el JSON y solo enviar la cantidad de elementos que quieres.

Comment: Oea administrar el json con php???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya lo he resuelto gracias por sus ideas, busque en la documentacion oficial de MetroUi (EL framework css que estoy utilizando) y encontre este link. https://metroui.org.ua/list.html resulta que este framework posee un uso de listas que me permite cargar un json y paginalo a antojo, es primera vez que uso este framework por eso mi desoconocimiento lo resolvi con el siguiente codigo.

```
<ul class="unstyled-list list icon-list"
                        data-role="list" 
                        data-show-pagination="true"
                        data-items="15"
                        data-items-steps="15, 25, 50, 100, 150"
                        data-show-items-steps="true"
                        data-show-list-info="true"
                        data-list-info-title="Mostrando $1 a $2 de $3 Icons"
                        data-sort-target="li"
                        data-sort-class="label"
                        data-cls-list-item="bg-orange-hover fg-dark"
                        data-source="{{asset('/js/icons/json/MaterialIcons.json')}}"></ul>
```

[image: Imagen_de_resultados]